# Cambio de valores a escala (0 - 100)

Tags: r, rstudio, matemáticas, scale

De casualidad alguien sabe cómo podría transformar un grupo de valores a una escala 0 - 100 sin que el mayor valor sea 100?

Tengo los siguientes valores estandarizados y estoy interesado en crear un indicador en el cual pueda interpretar de manera más clara estos resultados, desearía pasar este grupo de valores a una escala entre 0 a 100 tomando en cuenta que por ejemplo al aplicar la transformación el estado de Nevada que tiene un valor de 2.63 (Valor más alto)  no represente un 100%, estoy manejando el IDE RStudio.

Muchas Gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Lo que puedes intentar es utilizar el package `scales`. Este package tiene la función `rescale` que te permite escalar la data entre un rango the valores:

```
set.seed(123)                                     
data <- runif(100, - 2, 2)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
data_scale <- rescale(data, to = c(0, 100))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

Para llevar un vector de numéricos a una escala de 0 a 1, la formula clásica es:

```
(x-min(x))/((max(x))-min(x))
```

Multiplicándolo por 100 lo llevamos a una escala de 0 a 100, pero si además no queremos que el valor máximo sea 100, simplemente hay que hacer que el máximo sea el valor máximo del vector más un pequeño residuo:

```
(x-min(x))/((max(x)+1e-08)-min(x))*100
```

Ejemplo:

```
set.seed(2022)
x <- runif(10, -1, 1)

(x-min(x))/((max(x)+1e-08)-min(x))*100

 [1]  99.999999  78.201815  10.123059  64.835026  18.443636
 [6]  76.720102   4.176097   0.000000  42.421246  92.412839
```